# data-id Scroll down to the item when clicking

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to add an item data-id When i click on it 
I am trying to add a new item because I need to use Class and id 
An example of what I want to do

```
<a data-goto="#6">unint q</a>
```

when click scrool to  data-id="6"

```
<img src="https://mdajd.com/06/5b2s33.webp
    " loading="lazy" data-id="6" id="viewer" class="page">
```

Because my project requires more than 200 pictures sometimes

So I'm trying to add shortcuts

Are there ideas for action or solution? Thank you

Comment: Is this: `a data-goto="#6">unint q</a>` autogenerated? I.e. do you iterate through 1-200 elements and automatically set the value `6`?

Comment: no  I try to create an index that helps with quick access. I need in every 200 pictures to make 5 units

Comment: What is a `unit`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily with [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method with `scrollTop` property. You can increase/decrease animation duration currently it is set to 500.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var gotoId = $(this).data('goto');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("img[data-id='" + gotoId + "']").offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" data-goto="1">unint a</a>
  <a href="#" data-goto="2">unint b</a>
  <a href="#" data-goto="3">unint c</a>
  <a href="#" data-goto="4">unint d</a>
  <a href="#" data-goto="5">unint q</a>
</div>

unint a
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/ffffff" loading="lazy" data-id="1" id="viewer" class="page"> 
unint b
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/ffffff" loading="lazy" data-id="2" id="viewer" class="page"> 
unint c
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/ffffff" loading="lazy" data-id="3" id="viewer" class="page"> 
unint d
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/ffffff" loading="lazy" data-id="4" id="viewer" class="page"> 
unint q
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ff0000/ffffff" loading="lazy" data-id="5" id="viewer" class="page">
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks  i fix  with  this  code

```
<a href='#6' class='jumpto'>Unit 1</a> <span>===</span> <a href='#10' class='jumpto'>Unit 2</a>

<img src="https://mdajd.com/06/5b2s33.webp
    " loading="lazy" data-id="6" id="viewer" class="page">
<img src="https://mdajd.com/06/5b2s33.webp
    " loading="lazy" data-id="10" id="viewer" class="page">

$(".jumpto").on("click",function(e){
    var id_ = $(this).attr("href");
    id_ = id_.replace("#","");
    changePageNumber(id_);
});
function changePageNumber(id){
    var dataid = id;
    if (dataid > 0 && dataid <=limit ) {
        var scrollTop     = $("img[data-id='1']").offset().top,
        elementOffset = $("img[data-id='"+dataid+"']").offset().top,
        distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
            $("#viewerContainer").animate({scrollTop : distance}, "slow");
            $("#pageNumber").val(dataid);
            slideSelect(dataid);

    }
}
```